# Parameters for shel_exec to print pdf

Tags: php, shell

I want to print pdf file using php code.I am trying shel_exec() but not working.My code is

```
shell_exec("'C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe' /t C:\\billdoc_260.pdf \\192.168.0.122\\EPSON TM-T82II Receipt");
```

My path for adobe reader is 'C:/Program%20Files/Adobe/Reader%2010.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe' which is fine.

My path for pdf file is C:/billdoc_260.pdf which opens when i open in browser.

I have installed Epson printer and static Ip for that printer is 192.168.0.122 which is working and my printer name which my system displays on Ctrl+p for any pdf print is EPSON TM-T82II Receipt which is also working.

But still shel_exec() does not print the pdf.

I am not getting where i am wrong.

I have tried other solution also

```
$handle = printer_open("EPSON TM-T82II Receipt");
    printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
    printer_start_page($handle);
    $filename='billdoc_260.pdf';
    $fhandle=fopen($filename, 'r');
    echo $contents = fread($fhandle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($fhandle);
    printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
    printer_write($handle,$contents);
    printer_end_page($handle);
    printer_end_doc($handle);
    printer_close($handle);
```

It prints Raw text of pdf something like

```
%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream xœ•TMOÛ@½çWL
```

I am stuck only at printing part of my project.Please help.

Comment: Just a guess, but you probably need `'`-quotes around printer path in your `shell_exec` string, since it contains spaces.

Comment: many are having problems with acrobat reader, try using a different pdf reader.

Comment: Ok,can you please tell my parameters are right for printing.i am not sure about where to give Ip address and printer name.I want to confirm sequence of parameters.